# name 'Atno_to_Symbol' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and have been studing -coding- every single exemple of the document many of you have probably gone through as well. In the class section I ran into an error I have not been able to get rid of. I appreciate your help, letting me know what does this (Atno_to_Symbol) do and how do I defined. I also would like to understand why that method retuns a 'C'. this is the code of the class:

```
class atom(object):
    def __init__(self,atno,x,y,z):
        self.atno=atno
        self.position=(x,y,z)
    def symbol(self): # a class method
        return Atno_to_Symbol[atno]
    def __repr__(self): # overloads printing
        return '%d %10.4f %10.4f %10.4f' %(self.atno, self.position[0],self.position[1], self.position[2])
```

then this comes afterwards...

```
    >>> at=atom(6,0.0,1.0,2.0)
    >>> print(at)
    6     0.0000     1.0000     2.0000
    >>> at.symbol()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#59>", line 1, in <module>
    at.symbol()
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 6, in symbol
    return Atno_to_Symbol(atno)
****NameError: name 'Atno_to_Symbol' is not defined****
```

here I am supposed to get a 'C' instead fo that error

Thanks, fabianc!

Comment: `Atno_to_Symbol` looks like it's supposed to be a dictionary (or possibly a list or tuple) mapping atomic numbers to element symbols.  If this code came from an example somewhere, you apparently didn't copy the entire example - you're missing the definition or import of this object.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for coming into my question. At first I thought Atno_to_Symbol was some kind of predefined Python function. I searched for it and it is not. Then perhaps I had overlooked part of the example, perhaps a previous one, but not. I tried mofiying the code and kept getting the "not defined" message. Point at which I gave up and posted this question. Unfortunately this piece of code is aroun on the web in varies tools and resouces, for instance page 78 in this U of Harvard doc.  http://tdc-www.harvard.edu/Python.pdf. Thanks again, fabianc!

Comment: I guess that document was intended as more of an example of how you do things in Python, rather than code you could actually run.  You could always define it yourself: `Atno_to_Symbol = { 1:'H', 2:'He', 3:'Li', 4:'Be', 5:'B', 6:'C' }` to get you started.

Comment: In addition to it, I did edit the class method like this... def symbol(self): # a class method
  return Atno_to_Symbol[self.atno]... and then I got my 'C' at the end!. Thanks a lot Jason.